# No logro ponerlos de las misma medida los botones ¿Que puedo hacer al respecto?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar  sticky-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="ima/balon.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">

  </a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
     <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto  text-center">
      <a href="iniciar.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger "><img src="ima/registra2.png" alt=""> Registrate </a>
     <a href="iniciar.html" class="btn btn-outline-info  "><img src="ima/percentage.png" alt=""> Promoción</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-nav   ml-auto text-center">
      <a href="iniciar.html" class="btn btn-outline-success mr-2"><img src="ima/login.png" alt="">Iniciar sesión</a>
    </div>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Puedes subir todo el CSS de tu codigo para poderte ayudar mas facil?

Comment: haz probado de añadir la clase [btn-block](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#sizes) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con [btn-block](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#sizes) lo puedes decir que coja toda la anchura:

Ejemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar  sticky-top navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">Abrir</span>
   </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="ima/balon.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">

  </a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
     <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto  text-center">
      <a href="iniciar.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-block">Registrate </a>
     <a href="iniciar.html" class="btn btn-outline-info  mb-2 btn-block">Promoción</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-nav text-center">
      <a href="iniciar.html" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block">Iniciar sesión</a>
    </div>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: excelente Muchas gracias